# Get input file name in streaming hadoop program

Tags: python, input, streaming, hadoop, filesplitting

I am able to find the name if the input file in a mapper class using FileSplit when writing the program in Java.

Is there a corresponding way to do this when I write a program in Python (using streaming?)

I found the following in the hadoop streaming document on apache:

> See Configured Parameters. During the execution of a streaming job,
>   the names of the "mapred" parameters are transformed. The dots ( . )
>   become underscores ( _ ). For example, mapred.job.id becomes
>   mapred_job_id and mapred.jar becomes mapred_jar. In your code, use the
>   parameter names with the underscores.

But I still cant understand how to make use of this inside my mapper.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

According to the ["Hadoop : The Definitive Guide"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do)

Hadoop sets job configuration parameters as environment variables for Streaming programs. However, it replaces non-alphanumeric character with underscores to make sure they are valid names. The following Python expression illustrates how you can retrieve the value of the mapred.job.id property from within a Python Streaming script:

os.environ["mapred_job_id"]

You can also set environment variables for the Streaming process launched by MapReduce by applying the -cmdenv option to the Streaming launcher program (once for each variable you wish to set). For example, the following sets the MAGIC_PARAMETER environment variable:

-cmdenv MAGIC_PARAMETER=abracadabra

Comment: Looks like the property Krishnamutry needs is called "map.input.file" - that will likely appear as "map_input_file" environment variable to streaming job.

Comment: Note: the periods should be replaced with underscores

Answer (score 6):

By parsing the `mapreduce_map_input_file`(new) or <del>`map_input_file`</del>(deprecated) environment variable, you will get the map input file name.

Notice:
The two environment variables are **case-sensitive**, all letters are **lower-case**.

Comment: `map_input_file` works for hadoop 0.20.x for anyone stuck on an old cluster

Answer (score 0):

The new ENV_VARIABLE for Hadoop 2.x is MAPREDUCE_MAP_INPUT_FILE

Comment: You should use lower case 'mapreduce_map_input_file'