# How to get the name of input file in MRjob

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, mrjob

I'm writing a map function using mrjob.  My input will come from files in a directory on HDFS.  Names of the files contain a small but crucial piece information that is not present in the files.  Is there a way to learn (inside a map function) the name of the input file from which a given key-value pair comes?

I'm looking for an equivalent of this Java code:

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)reporter.getInputSplit();
String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map.input.file` property will give the input file name.

According to the [Hadoop - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do)

> The properties can be accessed from the job’s configuration, obtained in the old MapReduce API by providing an implementation of the configure() method for Mapper or Reducer, where the configuration is passed in as an argument. In the new API, these properties can be accessed from the context object passed to all methods of the Mapper or Reducer.

Comment: And more information can be found from Praveen's previous answer to a question similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449756/get-input-file-name-in-streaming-hadoop-program

Comment: Thanks, @PraveenSripati and @ChrisWhite, this is exactly what I needed!  To state it explicitly for future visitors: `fileName = os.environ['map_input_file']` does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using **HADOOP 2.x** with Python:

```
file_name = os.environ['mapreduce_map_input_file']
```

Comment: Are these listed somewhere online or do I have to browse through the source code to find them?!

Comment: @masu, I think these properties are automatically set by Hadoop Streaming framework:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7452439/1389089

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Configured+Parameters